# What input shapes are required for a classifier that is using a pre-trained network (Pytorch)?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I'm fairly new to deeplearning, python, and pytorch so please bear with me!

I'm trying to understand Transfer Learning in Pytorch using two different Pretrained Networks: Vgg11 and Densenet121.
I've run data of shape (3 x 224 x 224) through the "features" part of the above networks, and the output shapes are as follows:

Vgg11 features output shape: 512 x 7 x 7

Densenet121 features output shape: 1024 x 7 x7

Now, I'm trying to make my own Classifier to use instead of the Pre-trained one. Upon checking both pre-trained classifiers, I see the Vgg11 classifier has in the first layer:

> (0): Linear(in_features=25088, out_features=4096, bias=True)

While the Densenet121 has in the first layer:

> (classifier): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1000, bias=True))

The Vgg one makes sense, since if you flatten the output of the "features" part, you get 512 x 7 x 7 = 25,088.

How does the Densenet one have only 1024 dimensions? If you flatten the output of its "features" part, you get 1024 x 7 x 7 = 50,176

Are there steps that I am missing for either of them? Are there ways to check the input and output shapes of each layer and find out exactly what's happening?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in Table 1 in the [DenseNet paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.06993.pdf), DenseNet-121 uses something called [Global Average Pooling](https://alexisbcook.github.io/2017/global-average-pooling-layers-for-object-localization/), which is an extreme way of pooling where a tensor of dimensions `d x h x w` is reduced to `d x 1 x 1`.

Comment: Vikas, thank you! That seems to be the missing piece of the puzzle! :)

Do you mind expanding on why it is considered extreme?

Comment: Happy to help! It's considered an extreme way of pooling because, unlike your standard or average pooling stuff, this method squishes a whole activation map into just a single value. So, according to the formula, if there are 12 activation maps stacked, each of size of 24x24, each such map is squished into one value. Then the output becomes 12 x 1 x 1, which is a huge jump from 12 x 24 x 24.